# Upper bound of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a series: $$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x(\frac{3}{2k}-1)|^{2}}{k^5}$$ where $x \in C[-1,1]$. How can I bound this series? I think this inequality $$S \leq \max_{t\in[-1,1]}|x(t)|$$ are true, but  I don't know how I can proof this.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a contradiction in combining an absolute value and a square. Please double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing more about $x$, about all you can write is

$$S\le\max_{t\in[-1,\frac12]}x^2(t)\,\zeta(5)=\left(\max_{t\in[-1,\frac12]}|x(t)|\right)^2\,\zeta(5)$$

Comment: Why $t \in [-1, \frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: @mathmaniac: hehe, my little secret… Expand the terms.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality you claim is not true. Take $x(t)=1$ for all $t$ and note that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{5}} >1$. What you can say is $S\leq c \max \{|x(t)|^{2}: -1\leq t \leq 1\}$ where $c =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{5}} $.

Comment: Where is the square gone ?